# javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: EntityLocalServiceUtil

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I am created liferay project using **portal-7.1-ga3** and **liferay-intellij-plugin-2.0.5**

But if I call `EntityLocalServiceUtil.getEntities(-1, -1)` located in `service-api`  from `portlet-module` ie `(entity-web)`

It threw `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` exception.

Exported all packages of "entity-service-api" (com.entity.service.* in which Exception, model, service comes) and "entity-service-service" (com.entity.service.* in which model.impl, service etc comes) modules from bnd.bnd also imported those in portlet-module bnd.bnd.

```
Bundle-Name: entity-service-api
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.entity.service.api
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Export-Package:\
    com.entity.service.*
-check: EXPORTS
-includeresource: META-INF/service.xml=../entity-service-service/service.xml
```

```
Bundle-Name: entity-service-service
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.entity.service.service
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion: 1.0.0
Liferay-Service: true
Export-Package:\
    com.entity.service.*
```

```
Bundle-Name: entity-web
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.entity.web
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Export-Package: com.entity.web.constants
Import-Package:\
!javax.servlet.*,\
!com.entity.service.*,\
*
```

Also added model dependency in build.gradle

this is complete stacktrace

```
2023-07-13 13:20:49.205 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-7][PortalImpl:6899] javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/onlineshopping/product/service/service/ProductCategoryLocalServiceUtil
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/onlineshopping/product/service/service/ProductCategoryLocalServiceUtil
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    at com.liferay.taglib.servlet.PageContextWrapper.handlePageException(PageContextWrapper.java:173)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:747)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl$IndirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl.java:202)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:79)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.TransferHeadersHelperImpl$TransferHeadersRequestDispatcher.include(TransferHeadersHelperImpl.java:162)
    at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutTypeControllerImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutTypeControllerImpl.java:171)
    at com.liferay.portal.model.impl.LayoutImpl.includeLayoutContent(LayoutImpl.java:904)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:407)
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:174)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._processActionPerform(PortalRequestProcessor.java:706)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor._process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:646)
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:194)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.process(MainServlet.java:1067)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:598)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:575)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portal.apio.internal.architect.servlet.filter.APIDocumentationFilter.processFilter(APIDocumentationFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at com.liferay.friendly.url.internal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:372)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:98)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:119)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:103)
    at com.liferay.portal.apio.internal.architect.servlet.filter.APIDocumentationFilter.processFilter(APIDocumentationFilter.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:360)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.password.modified.PasswordModifiedFilter.processFilter(PasswordModifiedFilter.java:57)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.BaseAuthFilter.processFilter(BaseAuthFilter.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:260)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:263)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:144)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.servlet.filter.MonitoringFilter.processFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:178)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:65)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:49)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:764)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1388)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/onlineshopping/product/service/service/ProductCategoryLocalServiceUtil
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:398)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.render(PortletContainerImpl.java:205)
    at com.liferay.portlet.SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.render(SecurityPortletContainerWrapper.java:142)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.lambda$render$0(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:126)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper._render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:183)
    at com.liferay.portlet.RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.render(RestrictPortletContainerWrapper.java:124)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerUtil.render(PortletContainerUtil.java:212)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer._render(PortletRenderer.java:192)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.PortletRenderer.render(PortletRenderer.java:84)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doProcessTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:568)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.doDispatch(RuntimePageImpl.java:340)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:154)
    at com.liferay.portal.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageImpl.processTemplate(RuntimePageImpl.java:175)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.layoutconfiguration.util.RuntimePageUtil.processTemplate(RuntimePageUtil.java:94)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.layout.view.portlet_jsp._jspService(portlet_jsp.java:728)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/onlineshopping/product/service/service/ProductCategoryLocalServiceUtil
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:667)
    at com.liferay.taglib.servlet.PageContextWrapper.handlePageException(PageContextWrapper.java:173)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:2144)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcher.java:64)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl$IndirectRequestDispatcher.include(DirectRequestDispatcherFactoryImpl.java:202)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.doDispatch(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:79)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.include(ClassLoaderRequestDispatcherWrapper.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.TransferHeadersHelperImpl$TransferHeadersRequestDispatcher.include(TransferHeadersHelperImpl.java:162)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._render(PortletContainerImpl.java:870)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl.lambda$render$2(PortletContainerImpl.java:216)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.PortletContainerImpl._preserveGroupIds(PortletContainerImpl.java:395)
    ... 159 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/onlineshopping/product/service/service/ProductCategoryLocalServiceUtil
    at com.shopping.product.web.actions.ViewCategoryMVCRenderCommand.render(ViewCategoryMVCRenderCommand.java:35)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet.render(MVCPortlet.java:286)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:127)
    at com.liferay.portlet.ScriptDataPortletFilter.doFilter(ScriptDataPortletFilter.java:58)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:124)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:71)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.service(EndpointRegistration.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.ResponseStateHandler.processRequest(ResponseStateHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.DispatchTargets.doDispatch(DispatchTargets.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.servlet.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:48)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:564)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeRender(InvokerPortletImpl.java:660)
    at com.liferay.portlet.internal.InvokerPortletImpl.render(InvokerPortletImpl.java:357)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.lambda$render$0(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:280)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet._render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:383)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.portlet.MonitoringInvokerPortlet.render(MonitoringInvokerPortlet.java:278)
    at org.apache.jsp.html.portal.render_005fportlet_jsp._jspService(render_005fportlet_jsp.java:1534)
    ... 169 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.onlineshopping.product.service.service.ProductCategoryLocalServiceUtil cannot be found by com.shopping.product.web_1.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:419)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 188 more
2023-07-13 13:20:51.655 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-7][status_jsp:872] com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletContainerException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/onlineshopping/product/service/service/ProductCategoryLocalServiceUtil
2023-07-13 13:20:51.749 ERROR [liferay/monitoring-1][ParallelDestination:55] Unable to process message {destinationName=liferay/monitoring, response=null, responseDestinationName=null, responseId=null, payload=[{displayName=ProductCategory, portletId=com_shopping_product_web_ProductWebPortlet, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=0, name=com_shopping_product_web_ProductWebPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=null, stopWatch=0:00:16.158, timeout=0, user=null}}, {displayName=Search Bar, portletId=com_liferay_portal_search_web_search_bar_portlet_SearchBarPortlet_INSTANCE_templateSearch, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=2162, name=com_liferay_portal_search_web_search_bar_portlet_SearchBarPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:02.162, timeout=0, user=null}}, {displayName=User Personal Bar, portletId=com_liferay_product_navigation_user_personal_bar_web_portlet_ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarPortlet, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=2, name=com_liferay_product_navigation_user_personal_bar_web_portlet_ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.002, timeout=0, user=null}}, {displayName=Navigation, portletId=com_liferay_site_navigation_menu_web_portlet_SiteNavigationMenuPortlet, requestType=RENDER, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=33, name=com_liferay_site_navigation_menu_web_portlet_SiteNavigationMenuPortlet, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portlet, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:00.033, timeout=0, user=null}}, {referer=http://localhost:8080/, remoteAddr=127.0.0.1, requestURL=http://localhost:8080/c/portal/status.jsp_display, statusCode=400, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=Portal Request, duration=2438, name=/c/portal/status, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portal, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:02.438, timeout=-1, user=null}}, {referer=http://localhost:8080/, remoteAddr=127.0.0.1, requestURL=, statusCode=400, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=2486, name=/c/portal/status, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portal, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:02.486, timeout=-1, user=null}}, {referer=http://localhost:8080/, remoteAddr=127.0.0.1, requestURL=, statusCode=400, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=16243, name=/c/portal/layout, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portal, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:16.243, timeout=-1, user=null}}, {referer=http://localhost:8080/, remoteAddr=127.0.0.1, requestURL=, statusCode=400, userAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36, {attributes=null, companyId=20099, groupId=20126, description=null, duration=16436, name=/web/guest/home, namespace=com.liferay.monitoring.Portal, requestStatus=SUCCESS, stopWatch=0:00:16.436, timeout=-1, user=null}}], values={defaultLocale=en_US, companyId=20099, groupId=0, principalName=20103, permissionChecker=com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.TransientValue@1d6a6b8f, siteDefaultLocale=en_US, themeDisplayLocale=en_US}}
com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListenerException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:32)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.InvokerMessageListener.receive(InvokerMessageListener.java:74)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination$1.run(ParallelDestination.java:52)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask._runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:752)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$WorkerTask.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:664)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.statistics.portlet.PortletStatistics.processDataSample(PortletStatistics.java:112)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.statistics.portlet.CompanyStatistics.processDataSample(CompanyStatistics.java:209)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.statistics.portlet.ServerStatistics.processDataSample(ServerStatistics.java:117)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.statistics.portlet.ServerStatistics.processDataSample(ServerStatistics.java:35)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.messaging.MonitoringMessageListener.processDataSample(MonitoringMessageListener.java:93)
    at com.liferay.portal.monitoring.internal.messaging.MonitoringMessageListener.doReceive(MonitoringMessageListener.java:121)
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.BaseMessageListener.receive(BaseMessageListener.java:26)
    ... 5 more
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace (including possible root causes): ClassNotFoundException lists a class that it complains on, and we'd need that stacktrace and the root causes.

Comment: @OlafKock I edited question with stacktrace, give me solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds weird to me to declare the following in your web project:

```
Import-Package:\
!javax.servlet.*,\
!com.entity.service.*,\
*
```

namely, I assume that `com.entity.service` translates to the stacktrace's `com/onlineshopping/product/service/service`. You're *explicitly not importing* the package, thus it can't be found.

As a bonus, you might want to look into not using the `*LocalServiceUtil` classes any more, and rather use the raw OSGi service as `@Reference EntityLocalService` (works well - and only - within a `@Component`)

More details/items to check in the [7.1 Service-Builder sample](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/7.1/liferay-workspace/apps/service-builder/basic)

Comment: I tried your given solution but problem not solved. Is there any other solutions ?